# setBackgroundDrawable not working properly

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-drawable, xml-drawable

In my application, I am using actionbarsherlock. I use

`getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrwable(R.drawable.test).`

It works fine, the color is showed as expected, however when I go to another activity and go back to the main activity. The bar color is changed to black (in my program, I dont set black for the backgrounddrawble and just call `setSupportAction().setBackgroundDrawable` in `onStart()`). However, if I change the code to

`getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff550000)));`

The app works fine. When I click on back button, the color is set to 0xff55000 which is expected.

Comment: try it in Oncreate() method

Comment: it has been solved. The problem is because of the race condition. The ActionBar object is obtained by other thread so the getSupporrtActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest not to use the color code directly this way while you are trying to set the color programmatically. It will not take it. just try out this way..

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(mContext.getResources().getColor(Color.BLACK)));
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: The Drawable file is a layer-list drawable and I define the gradient shape in it. The problem here is that even I declare a GradientDrawable object programmatically, and use setBackgroundDrawable(object). The actionbar doesnt turn to the expected color, it just turns black when I go back to the main activity. However, if I click on any button on action bar, it turns to expected color which is defined in the drawable file. So I think that when the action "click" on back button happens, the app is not ready to get the defined drawable file, it only works with color drawable file. Am I correct???

Comment: Color.BLACK is not a color ressource id, but a color value. Use new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work well for me either, specially if I use with the navigation drawer toggle list. In my case, if i don't use the toggle, the background goes white during a second and then load the background drawable. If I use the toggle, the background remains white.

I had to use a custom view to achive the effect I wanted to get instead of changing the background.

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the same issue, it happens that calling getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable twice does not work.
If I only call it only once in the onCreate is works. If I put the code in the onResume, it works for the first onResume, but it is set to grey for any other onResume